# delphi - selecting a row in TdbGrid if i know the row's ID from the DB

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7 and ms SQL server 2008. I have a DBGrid (actuaty a custom control called TEnhDBGrid, if you know it) and an ADO connection.
I'm using a ADOQuery to populate my grid:

```
with dbMod.clientQuery do
begin
  sql.text:='select * from client order by id';
  open;
end;
clientGrid.Columns[0].visible:=false;
clientGrid.Columns[1].width:=110;
clientGrid.Columns[2].width:=170;
clientGrid.Columns[3].width:=100;
clientGrid.Columns[4].width:=100;
```

The field for the "client" table in the DB, that the query returns are:
[image]

I want to select the row with a specific ID in the grid, and i can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a [locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Locate) in the TADOQuery. This will position the grid where ID is 5.

```
dbMod.clientQuery.Locate('id', 5, []);
```

Comment: or: `clientGrid.FieldColumns['id'].visible := false; clientGrid.FieldColumns['nume'].Width := 100;` etc.